# Windows 10 To Go still requires "fixed" drive?

Tags: windows, usb, usb-flash-drive, windows-10, windows-to-go

More details: http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/windows-10-to-go-still-required-fixed-drive.378528/

Unfortunately, TechNet was of no help either: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e616ce06-8135-4a5c-a7f5-19d6bc76d5a4/windows-10-to-go-still-requires-fixed-drive?forum=win10itprosetup#a63c1381-e904-4ad8-989e-22ce01b5298b

Comment: OK, that tutorial tailed... Error at creation of VHD step. W/E, I still prefer Hiren's BootCD.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is still required because the WinToGo creator tool creates 2 partitions and in Windows this requires a fixed drive.

Comment: I see. How about these websites that claim you can use a removable drive via a VHD file instead of burning files directly onto the partitions?:
http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/129
http://www.easy2boot.com/add-payload-files/wintogo/

Comment: the links tell the same that I do: "For this reason we cannot use a Removable-type of USB Flash drive for WindowsToGo and use a single NTFS partition, because Windows will only mount one partition on a Removable-type of drive. "

Comment: Have you read the whole thing? It clearly states the usage of VHD on removable drives later on. Plus, the first link is entirely about that "hack".

Comment: @magicandre1981 - I need to do the same and I plan to put WTG on VHD/ VHDX. Its more flexible and portable than a USB.  Can copy VHD to Internal or External drives

Comment: @magicandre1981 - PS: How did you end up going about it?